# Python: Removing duplicates from a huge csv file (memory issues)

Tags: python, memory, duplicates

I have a csv file that is very big, containing a load of different people. Some of these people come up twice. Something like this:

```
Name,Colour,Date
John,Red,2017
Dave,Blue,2017
Tom,Blue,2017
Amy,Green,2017
John,Red,2016
Dave,Green,2016
Tom,Blue,2016
John,Green,2015
Dave,Green,2015
Tom,Blue,2015
Rebecca,Blue,2015
```

I want a csv file that contains only the most recent colour for each person. For example, for John, Dave, Tom and Amy I am only interested in the row for 2017. For Rebecca I will need the value from 2015.

The csv file is huge, containing over 10 million records (all people have a unique ID so repeated names don't matter). I've tried something along the lines of the following:

```
Open csv file
Read line 1.
If person is not in "seen" list, add to csv file 2
Add person to "Seen" list.
Read line 2...
```

The problem is the "seen" list gets massive and I run out of memory. The other issue is sometimes the dates are not in order so an old entry gets into the "seen" list and then the new entry won't overwrite it. This would be easy to solve if I could sort the data by descending date, but I'm struggling to sort it with the size of the file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If the whole csv file can be stored in a list like:

```
csv_as_list = [
    (unique_id, color, year),
    …
]
```

then you can `sort` this list by:

```
import operator

# first sort by year descending
csv_as_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
# then, since the Python sort is stable, by unique_id
csv_as_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

and then you can:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import operator, itertools

for unique_id, group in itertools.groupby(csv_as_list, operator.itemgetter(0)):
    latest_color = next(group)[1]
    print(unique_id, latest_color)
```

(I just used `print` here, but you get the gist.)

If the csv file cannot be loaded in-memory as a list, you'll have to go through an intermediate step that uses disk (e.g. SQLite).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your csv file to read.
2. Read line by line, append user to `final_list` if his ID is not already found in there. If it is found, check the year of your `current_data`, with your `final_list` data. If the current data has a more recent entry, just change the date of your user in `final_list`, along with the color associated with it.
3. Only then, when your `final_list` is done, will you write a new csv file.

If you want this task to be faster, you want to...

- Optimize your loops.
- Use standard python functions and/or libraries coded in C.

If this is still not optimized enough... learn C. Reading a csv file in C, parsing it with a separator, and iterating through an array is not hard, even in C.

Comment: That's kind of what I tried to start with, but struggling to store multiple million entries in a list!

Comment: final_list should, in this case, be a dictionary, certainly not a list, but it's of no use if the memory cost is prohibitive. You could, of course, write the list to a file, but O(n^2) and needing to do disk I/O for every check is going to be extremely slow. A database can at least generate a multi-column index that will ensure decent performance.

Comment: Agreed on performance. But you don't need a dictionnary. Knowing `[0]` gives the ID, `[1]` the color and `[2]` the year is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I see two obvious ways to solve this that don't involve keeping huge amounts of data in memory:

1. Use a database instead of CSV files
2. Reorganise your CSV files to facilitate sorting.

Using a database is fairly straightforward. I expect you could could even use the SQLite that comes with Python. This would be my preferred option, I think. To get the best performance, create an index of (person, date).

The second involves letting the first column of your CSV file be the person ID and the second column be the date. Then you could sort the CSV file from the commandline, i.e. sort myfile.csv. This will group all entries for a particular person together, and provided your date is in a proper format (e.g. YYYY-MM-DD), the entry of interest will be the last one. The Unix sort command is not known for its speed, but it's very robust.